# UML Designer 7.1 does not display full dialog content

Tags: uml-designer

While using UML Designer 7.1 on linux Arch Gnome3 desktop, dialog box content does not show botton and left content. It makes preference dialog box validation not possible.
Other eclipse based tools does not have this behavior. Is there a way to fix this problem ?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a bug, can you fill a detailed issue with screenshot on the UML Designer bug tracker: https://github.com/ObeoNetwork/UML-Designer/issues

Thanks for your feedback!